# How to search and replace precisely

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which content is quite like following

G12

G10,11

GO12

GO10,12

What I am trying to do is replace all the 'G' with '' but not replacing 'GO' to 'O'.

I was trying to do with regular expressions, so first I am dealing with the lines without a comma

```
with open(file) as f:
for line in f:
if re.match(r"%s[0-9]+" % 'G', line):
    input = line.strip('G')
```

And it turns out that the "G10,11\n" string is matching the regex pattern either, which makes me confused.

Is there any wrong with my statement, OR is there any simpler approach to do this?
Many thanks,

Comment: `r"%s[0-9]+" % 'G'` will always result in the string `'G[0-9]+'` which is then used as the regular expression.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some alternatives here. Translating your requirements directly gets you: `G(?!O)`, which you can replace with empty string. Which could be done like so:

```
line = re.sub(r"G(?!O)", "", line)
```

`G` matches a `G`, `(?!O)` matches only if the following character is not a `O`.

You may want to use `G(?=\d)` instead, to match `G`s followed by a digit.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still wondering, why my regex r"%s[0-9]+" is matching the lines with a comma, I thought only r"%s[0-9]+,[0-9]+" matches the lines like G10,11.

Comment: @Floyd If you stored the result from `re.match` and looked at what it matched, you could see that it would only match `G10` in `G10,11`. But you only check “does this match or not”, and then process the line on its own. So `G10` matches in `G10,11` but then you are working on `G10,11` again which is why you see that part too.

Comment: @poke Thank you! I think understand your explanation, but how can I  write a regex to avoid this incorrectly matching?

Comment: @Floyd You could require the match to be until the end of the line, by adding the `$` character to the expression: `G[0-9]+$`

Comment: @Floyd You’re welcome! Please consider accepting this answer anyway to mark this question as solved, even if it wasn’t what you ended up using.